# serverless redshift - secret manager create

Tags: aws-secrets-manager, amazon-redshift-serverless

I am trying to create a secret manager for the purpose of using lambda in serverless redshift.
The redshift cluster created on the security password type selection screen is not visible, so it cannot be created.
Any solution?

Comment: remember to specify workgroupname param or you will keep getting cluster does not exist error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secrets manager "new secret" wizard does not show any serverless Redshift workgroups.

You can however create an *other* database and enter hostname and more, and edit the secret later to modify the database type in the secret.